# Is it possible to have the first item in a flexbox column-based list be 100% while the others are not?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I think not, but wonder if anyone else might have a solution.

Here's what I get now using my column based flexbox layout:

[image]

But I actually want is this:

[image: Possible?]

My markup is a simple UL with LI's. I have flexbox set on the ul and a column based layout option, and i specify the height so that it wraps to the right. I'm using Bootstrap 4 flexbox layout for the columns on the individual LI's. As you can imagine, if i specify the first item to be 100% width, then all the direct li's that fit the specified height will also be 100%.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#row1 {
    padding: 10px;
}
#row2 {
    padding: 10px;
}
#row3 {
    flex:2;
    display: flex;
}
#col1 {
    flex :0 0 240px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#col2 {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 1;
}
#col3 {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Menu</div>
    <div id="row2">
      <h1>Care & Service Center</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="row3">
      <div id="col1">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>Col1 - Row 1</li>
          <li>Col1 - Row 2</li>
          <li>Col1 - Row 3</li>
          <li>Col1 - Row 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="col2">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>Col2 - Row 1</li>
          <li>Col2 - Row 2</li>
          <li>Col2 - Row 3</li>
          <li>Col2 - Row 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="col3">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>Col3 - Row 1</li>
          <li>Col3 - Row 2</li>
          <li>Col3 - Row 3</li>
          <li>Col3 - Row 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @edmar-miyake, but unfortunately I need a ul that can't have modified markup.

Comment: @DavidPanzarella You can still have the ul's in each column div. Check my edit.

Comment: while that's true for this example, its not true for my use case as i need a simple ul with nested ul's for the mobile implementation. Sure i can add more markup, but that complicates things for mobile in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a padding on the `ul` and give the first item `position: absolute` you will get this, would that be an option for you?

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
ul li {
  border: 1px solid black
}
ul li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>1
  </li>
  <li>2
  </li>
  <li>3
  </li>
  <li>4
  </li>
  <li>5
  </li>

  <li>6
  </li>
  <li>7
  </li>
  <li>8
  </li>
  <li>9
  </li>
  <li>10
  </li>

  <li>11
  </li>
  <li>12
  </li>
  <li>13
  </li>
  <li>14
  </li>
  <li>15
  </li>

</ul>
```